# impement operator [] like in QVariantMap for QML

Tags: qt, qml, operator-keyword

Main goal is make ContextProperty for QML like QVariantMap with access operator []:

For example cpp file:

```
...
QVariantMap qvm; qvm["zero"] = "it's OK";
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qvm",qvm);
...
```

qml file:

```
console.log("qvm[zero] === "+qvm["zero"]); // output: qvm[zero] === it's OK
```

but with my class:

```
class MyStore : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyStore(QObject* parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){
  }
  MyStore(const MyStore &other,QObject* parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){ store = other.store; }
  ~MyStore(){}
  inline const QVariant &operator[](QString i) const {
    static const QVariant val(store[i]);
    return val;
  }
  QVariantMap store;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStore);
```

cpp file:

```
store.store["zero"] = "OK only in cpp";
qDebug("main: store[\"zero\"] == %s", store["zero"].toString().toAscii().data()); // output:   main: store["zero"] == "OK only in cpp"
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mystore",&store);
```

qml file:

```
console.log("qml: mystore[\"zero\"] === "+mystore["zero"]); // output: qml: mystore["zero"] === undefined
```

How to implement for output:

> qml: mystore["zero"] === "OK only in cpp"

?

Comment: Does [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) help?

Comment: There is no need for static variable but only `return QVariant val(store[i]);`. The static simply not used correctly. Read about statics in some good C++ book.

Comment: @JarMan This not solve, I can use setContextObject instead setContextProperty as workaround, but I want is what I want.

Comment: @AlexanderV "return QVariant val(store[i]);" prodused the "warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'val' returned". And your comment not give solution.

Comment: `QVariant operator[](QString i) const {
    return store[i];
  }` no reference and copy the variant value out.

Comment: @AlexanderV the problem is more complex than subtleties of language, need worked solution for cpp and qml bridge